# How can I give nested structs access to fields of their parent classes without making those fields public or internal?

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

I have a `double[,]` field in a class, and it's important that direct access to it not be given over to the outside, so I created a read-write property to control it and made it `private`. I also have a nested `struct` in the class, which I want to keep as a value-type. The struct itself has a `double[,]` field, which again, is controlled by a corresponding read-write property. Given certain conditions, if the property is assigned a value that's invalid in a specific way, it throws a custom `exception`. One of the arguments I need to pass to the `exception` is based on the value of the `double[,]` field from the parent class, but I don't seem to be able to access it from within the struct without making it `public` or `internal`. I've tried both `protected` and `private` but neither works. Is there another workaround?

```
class myClass {
    protected double[,] classField;
    public double[,] classProperty {
        get { return (double[,])classField.Clone();
        set { /* code to validate the value and assign it */ }
    }
    private struct myStruct {
        private double[,] structField;
        public structProperty{ 
            get { return (double[,])structField.Clone(); }
            set {
                if (!validate(value)) 
                    throw new customException(classField.getLength(1));
                structField = (double[,])value.Clone();
            }
        }
        //other fields, constructors, and methods...
    }
    //other fields, constructors, and methods...
}
```

I was considering possibly accessing the property instead of the field, but I would need the value of the property for the particular instance that contanins the struct instance in question. Is there maybe something like `this.parent` (I did try that and that didn't work, but maybe some workaround similar in concept)?

Comment: can I check: you want to access myClass.classField here from myStruct?

Comment: yes, that's right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want `myStruct` to talk to the `classField` of the containing `myClass` instance.

If that is the case: then the problem isn't *accessibility* - it already has access; the problem is *scope*. As far as the compiler is concerned, nesting here is unrelated to instancing, so the problem is that `myStruct` has no specific *instance* of `classProperty` to talk to. That's why the error is:

> Error CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'myClass.classField'

rather than accessibility:

> Error CS0122  'myClass.classField' is inaccessible due to its protection level

In fact, `classField` can be `private` in terms of accessibility: a nested type can see `private` members of the containing type.

What you would need is to do something like:

```
private struct myStruct
{
    private readonly myClass _obj;
    public myStruct(myClass obj) => _obj = obj;
    // ...
}
```

and then instead of just `classField`, you need to tell it to talk to `_obj.classField` to tell it the instance. You would also need to construct the `myStruct` passing *in* the specific `myClass` to which it relates.

Basically: the `this.parent` concept you mention in the question is not implicit - you need to implement it yourself.

Comment: This does not compile, can structs have constructors?

Comment: @Jerry yes, they can; I'm using C# 7.3 syntax here - if you're using an earlier compiler: `public myStruct(myClass obj) { _obj = obj; }`

Comment: I understand my error, it was complaining that `stuctField` wasn't being assigned, I was working with the OP's code. Thanks Marc

Comment: lol the fact that you have to explicitly mimic the this.parent functionality with parameters is real janky, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: @TaraStahler the point is: C# doesn't assume that your struct should track the "containing" instance in any way - `myStruct` is defined purely by the code you write - no hidden automatic extra fields. This a: means you fully understand the size/scope of the type you're creating (which can be important), b: means that it doesn't magically become non-blittable (which having a field that is a reference to some parent would do; blittable === `T : unmanaged` for this purpose), and c: doesn't limit your usage of `myStruct` instances to a 1:1 relationship with `myClass` instances

Comment: @MarcGravell I would argue that you would still be able to use the parameter method even if parent functionality was implicit if your needs were not just 1:1. For point b, there is a lot that's already unmanaged anyway, (such as using the Clone() method, and then using the CLR to convert the result of the clone to a double[,]). As for understanding the size/scope, that would really just be a matter of educating yourself.

Comment: @TaraStahler I meant `unmanaged` in a very specific context - the context of the `T : unmanaged` constraint; `Clone()` wouldn't make it unmanaged or not, but the array field `structField` would, as would a `myClass` field